# Aligning text in rotated multirow

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, alignment

I'm making a somewhat complicated figure and I'm having trouble aligning the text in some of my row captions. The below is a MWE that shows my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\def\rowheight{2cm}  % Height of each row
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}  % Space between rows inside block
\def\blockspace{5mm}  % Space between blocks
\def\colwidth{.25\textwidth}  % Width of each column
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}  % Space between columns
\begin{tabular}{cc|ccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Block 1}} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c} &
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{270}{Row 1} \\
     & \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c} &
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{270}{Row 2} \\[\blockspace]
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Block 2}} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c} &
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{270}{Row 1} \\
     & \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c} &
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{270}{Row 2} \\[\blockspace]
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Block 3}} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c} &
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{270}{Row 1} \\
     & \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c} &
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{270}{Row 2}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled]

I'd like all the captions on the sides to be center aligned either to their respective blocks (each block is a set of two rows) or to the rows themselves. However, the current configuration doesn't really align them properly, and other configurations with `origin=c` or `origin=l` have performed even worse when I tested them.

How do I appropriately align the side captions? Alternatively, is there a better way to lay out this kind of figure than `tabular`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right texts are easy to handle. You just need to add `adjustbox` package, add `valign=c` to each image so their baselines are in the middle of images, and use `\rotatebox[origin=c]...`; it will rotate and place texts right in the middle. Also, if you have a number of images with the same options, `adjustbox` has a nice solution to avoid repetition, `\adjustboxset{...}`, which will insert all settings specified inside to each instance of `\includegraphics`. It can be set globally in a preamble or locally in a group.

I find rotations in `multirow` a bit tricky. if I use anything else than one line of text, it usually shifts the content. Adding a small adjustment can correct it; use the third optional parameter.

Final note, try to avoid `\def`. Either `\newcommand` for macros or `\newlength\name` for length names (followed by `\setlength\name{...}`) are better options because they warn about accidental overwriting something that is already defined, whereas `\def` silently change them.

Your example

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newlength\rowheight
\newlength\colwidth
\newlength\blockspace
\newlength\smallspace
\newlength\multirowcor

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \setlength\rowheight{2cm}  % Height of each row
  \setlength\colwidth{.25\textwidth}  % Width of each column
  \setlength\blockspace{1cm}
  \setlength\smallspace{0.9cm}
  \setlength\multirowcor{-5mm}
  \adjustboxset{width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight,valign=c}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}  % Space between rows inside block
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}  % Space between columns
  \begin{tabular}{cc|ccc}
    \multirow{2}*[\multirowcor]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Block 1}}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{Row 1} \\[\smallspace]
    & \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{Row 2} \\[\blockspace]
    \multirow{2}*[\multirowcor]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Block 2}}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{Row 1} \\[\smallspace]
    & \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{Row 2} \\[\blockspace]
    \multirow{2}*[\multirowcor]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Block 3}}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{Row 1} \\[\smallspace]
    & \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{Row 2}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that uses  `tikz` to get the desired effect.
**If you are not familiar with `tikz`, I wouldn't recommand this solution** for you because there is a lot to fathom before being able to modify it as you want.
Just know that *nearly* everything is possible with `tikz`.

In your case, rather than using a table(ular), I used a `foreach` loop to place the image. Then, I defined a node named `block` with the text `block` that is located between the `cell00` and `cell10`, rotated by 90° and shifted by a *little bit* on the x axis.

I then defined the `row1` and `row2` nodes to be 25 units on the right of the desired cells, rotated around their north anchor by -90°.

If you are asking yourself "Why does it have to be so complicated?". It is because `tikz` allow you to do so much and overcomes all limitations that are present in `table` for example.
Anis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\foreach \y in {0,1}{
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
    \node (cell\y\x)at (4*\x,3*\y){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
}   
}
\node[rotate=90](block) at ($(cell00)!0.5!(cell10) -(2,0)$) {block1};
\node[right of = cell02,right = 30,rotate=-90,anchor=north](row1) {Row1};
\node[right of = cell12,right = 30,rotate=-90,anchor=north](row2) {Row2};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=6cm]
\foreach \y in {0,1}{
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \node (cell\y\x)at (4*\x,3*\y){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
    }   
}
\node[rotate=90](block) at ($(cell00)!0.5!(cell10) -(2,0)$) {block1};
\node[right of = cell02,right = 30,rotate=-90,anchor=north](row1) {Row1};
\node[right of = cell12,right = 30,rotate=-90,anchor=north](row2) {Row2};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\centering
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```